# No SNMP daemon restart on setting engine Id

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap, snmpd, snmpv2c

Currently, SNMP daemon restart when engine id is set. This causes service delay to clients. This need to be avoided and any signal like SIGHUP to be used for sync the new configuration.

I used SIGHUP i am able to achieve that demon is not restarted but the updated engine id is not reflecting in the configuration files.

ie.., `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf`

Appreciate if anyone is helping with a patch that should update the configurations...

If it is not expected to do the changes using signup, Kindly let me know the
impact will create.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you modify the configuration file then send SIGHUP? Shouldn't that be the usual process?

Comment: yup manually i modified the configuration file and sighup is used, but changes were not persisted in snmpd.conf file... 

please help me with the patch

Comment: Are you saying that snmpd.conf changed itself back to the original values?

Comment: yes thats true.. :( when you restart the demon /etc/restart-snmpd , changes are present but if you do sighup to resync configurations it modified is back to normal values ie..., changed value is not reflected.

Comment: That's really strange.

Comment: Please submit a bug report to the net-snmp developers if you want the behavior to change.

Comment: I logged a ticket in the below link, But no one is responding on it, Could you please let me know that is that the right way of submitting the bug report, this is the first time i am logging the ticket here. Please help
https://sourceforge.net/p/snmpsighupforengineid/tickets/1/